# How to edit the address bar using java?

Tags: java, refresh

NOT JavaScript. From a java code I have figured out how to open a browser and make it go to a site but who can I edit the address bar on the browser.

Also how could I refresh that page?

Comment: Are you writing a Java applet or a Java desktop app?

Comment: *"From a java code I have figured out how to open a browser and make it go to a site..."* Okay: **How are you doing that?** In what environment? With what technology? Show the code, or at least talk about it. What are the odds that the specific technique you're using might, just possibly, have *something* to do with answering your question?

Answer (score 2):

I simply can't directly do such a thing. You can open a browser with a site just because you ask to the underlying operating system but I don't see any normal way to interact directly with an executable to instruct commands.

You can try asking to the OS to open a specific URL with the default browser, so that your page will be updated to the new URL you are passing but no any "mechanized" way..

Comment: Thank you, how would I do that then?

Answer (score 0):

Use **WebDriver** API from Selenium 2 or browser specific **command-line arguments** for opening a new page. You can also create an HTTP cache, fetch constant URL and re-map it in the cache - great choice as it is both complicated and laborious :D.